# Capturing Data From a PayPal Buy Now Button

Tags: php, forms, paypal

I've looked into this, and I've seen some places saying you can use CURL for this, but I'm not convinced that'd work the way I'm after.

What I want to do is to have a temporary holding page between the website I'm working on and the PayPal website. The sole purpose of this holding page is to cache the data about the item being bought in the database so it can be checked against the returned data from PayPal as an additional security measure. (The buttons are already dynamically encrypted)

So, what I'm looking to do is have a scenario along these lines:

1. Buy Now button clicked
2. Form submits data to holding page
3. Holding page adds data to database
4. Holding page sends user and data to PayPal to process the transaction

The problem, of course, is that transferring the `$_POST` data isn't straightforward. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to go about this using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own button and hide the real paypal button.  On clicking your button do an AJAX post and do server side processing.

If the response is ok, render an HTTP 200 response and in your onsuccess in $.ajax, trigger a click to the real buy now button (or trigger the paypal API, however this works in your setup)

If the response i bad, render an HTTP 402 response and in your onerror, do whatever you would do to alert the user that it failed.

This way, you don't need to redirect the user twice - which is kinda jarring...

Whatever form you have, you can use jQuery to send the form as AJAX..

Something like this should do:

```
var data = $('form').serialize();
$.post('url', data);
```

Comment: I know my scenario isn't the most elegant, but when that's what the boss tells you to do... I'd considered using jQuery, but I don't want it to be dependent on JavaScript - some of our clients and their clients aren't the most tech-savvy and have very old browsers with JS turned off.

Comment: @yoda if your clients have JS turned off, then PayPal's website likely won't work properly anyway.

Comment: @yoda - Its 2012, if you're not using javascript, you're hardly using the web anymore.. JS is pretty universal and jQuery is quite browser compatible even back to IE6..  i'm not sure how your holding page would work without using javascript...

Comment: PayPal has a NoScript version - and people do consciously choose not to allow JS to run.

Answer (score 0):

Having created, for example, `holding.php`, have a look at this blog post: http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Or you could put into the database the things you want to compare with before the page where the button is?

Comment: But will (and I admit I don't have a lot of experience with CURL) that take you to the PayPal website when you use it, which is what I need it to do?